# jquery SLOW to call get or post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

bit of a heisenbug here...

Have a PHP/codeigniter app here. Pretty sure the controller/model etc. are sound and without bugs. Gotta be a client-side problem...

Very simple code like this in a page:

```
<div id="stuff">I'm empty now!</div>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var stuffID = <?=$id?>;
    $.post('/event/viewStuff/'+stuffID,
        function(response) {
            $('#stuff').html(response);
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

After loading the above, the "stuff" div now has a grid of stuff, plus links to page through them 10 at a time, which look like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#stuff').html('Wait please...'); $.get('http://localhost/event/viewInvitees/22/30', function(response) {$('#stuff').html(response); }); return false">Next Page</a>
```

But every time I click these links, the page freezes for 4-5 seconds, doing what I don't know - no network activity, no nothing chrome debugger. Then the "stuff" div reloads with the results. Also - the "Please wait" message is not shown. Weird thing is - when I yank the "document.ready()" function, reload the page, and just click on a bare / hard-coded paging link like the one above, things fires away fast as expected.

Thanks so much for taking time to read.

NEW INFO:

xdebug profile shows nothing unusual - about a 1 second functional call back to the controller/view to return content as expected.

Chrome profiler shows this - a stupid, unexplained idle:

[image]

---

Any additional insight on the "b.event.remove()" jquery function that's taking 6+ seconds? That seems to be the issue?

Comment: why are you using php direktly in your jquery ? i mean, if you use ajax/jquery post... you could handle this with json. not recommended to do this like you do!

Comment: Sounds like the request is being sent synchronously, but I don't know why that would be since you're using `$.get()`. What version of jQuery is this?

Comment: @Dwza I'm constructing this page with 3 different PHP views - the wrapper has the overall "stuff" identifier I need to use.

Comment: @cookie-monster could be - no idea why though. Using version 1.10.1. Also tested with .post() - same odd behavior.

Comment: do some profiling of php and jQuery scripts

Comment: "Bit of a heisenbug here" lol ^.^

Comment: @user3550402, I would try to build this functionality with a static HTML file that talks to a vanilla PHP (no Cake) script. Just see if you're still getting delays once you pull out large framework/db components. Once you've ruled out that it works with the minimum technology requirements, start adding pieces back and see which is the culprit.

Comment: @naomik stop giggling and start fixing my problems! :)

Comment: @user3550402 will try that - but its killing me since the page components seem to determine whether there's a delay or faux-synchronous behavior. Also I have another page that's constructed exactly the same (different controller+view) but output is the same - and no issue there.

Comment: @charlietfl xdebug shows nothing weird. Digging into chrome debugging now...

Comment: Any additional insight on the "b.event.remove()" jquery function that's taking 6+ seconds? That seems to be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it - but don't understand the root cause:

As described above - there was a massive delay every time I clicked the "Next Page" link.

Javascript profiling proved that jquery 1.9.1 was hanging for ~6 seconds on b.event.remove(). No idea why. I thought to myself: "Hmm... maybe I've triggered some weirdly inefficient tear-down function. That #stuff div is rather large (lots of sub-forms etc)."

So I tried clearing it out first by adding this command to the link click code:

```
$('#stuff').html('');
```

No dice. Then I tried:

```
$('#stuff').empty();
```

Same deal - took even longer.

On a lark I then tried the non-jquery method:

```
document.getElementById('stuff').innerHTML = '';
```

It worked! The rest of the click-code executed immediately - no more delay!

Question is why??????

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

try to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

in mysql PDO is something like this thats costs performance... so just test it.